# Passing an input to a service and saving the result to DB in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a Django application that involves a model with five fields. In the case of one of these fields, I want users to enter a bunch of text, which I then want to submit to a service (via a function call) and save the result. To provide a visual representation:

[image]

How does one best play this? One option to me would be to override the save() function, but the types are different - I want the form to show a models.TextField field but save it as the results of a URLField would be saved. Equally, when displayed, I want the user to edit not the URL but rather the text retrieved from that URL.

Comment: Couldn't you make the request by extending the `is_valid` method on the class?  That way the form would only be valid if you received a successful response from the external service.  Then you can add a field to the form that would be saved in your database model and remove the field that contains the text.  So once it is *valid*, you can save it with the data you want, not the text that was inputed by the user.

Comment: Perhaps a little clarification: I would much prefer a solution that would also workn between types, e.g. take an image, give a URL, save URL to model.

Comment: What do you mean by take an image? Do you mean it could either be text or an image?

Comment: The form field would be for an image upload. The image is uploaded, then sent to an image processing server, which returns a URL. The URL is then saved to the model. Upon retrieval, the URL and/or the image, too, are returned (I'm not picky).

Comment: I think you could follow the same idea as I have provided in my answer for this too.

Comment: Updated my answer with an example implementation at django model layer. I haven't performed heavy testing, just tried it with a basic test app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is no easy standard way to solve your problem. (<del>This is why I don't provide any code, treat this as a long comment instead of
a solution.</del> The update provides sources for one of the solutions discussed in this answer.) There are only solutions with pros and cons depending on
your circumstances.

## Problems:

1. Asynchronous processing: You are accessing an external service and
   the request may take some time to complete.
   For this reason this operation should be done in
   an asynchronous way (both storing and retrieving data from the
   external service). The problem with this is that django wasn't
   really invented for async tasks, there are only hacky async
   solutions for django.

   - By accessing the external service directly in a non-async way from
     your django backend your site may hang up for long periods when
     the external service fails (in worst case with long timeout
     settings at different points between your server and the external
     servers). For a not too serious site we can assume that the
     external service will work in most of the cases and if not, then
     a little bit of downtime for our servers is acceptable.
   - Doing async processing with a django backend is not only hacky and
     messy but a really good solution is sometimes nearly impossible.

     On really good solution I mean something that looks like a solution
     you write with tools/frameworks that have been invented for async
     servers (golang, gevent). Typical async solutions with django
     often involve very complex architecture and code compared to a
     solution with pure golang or gevent server code.

     For example if you have to serve the client some data that you have
     to retrieve from an external service then if response comes with
     high latency from the external service then your django backend
     will have to wait for the response anyway.
     If you do the waiting in an "asnyc-helper" server
     (celery, twisted, or gevent) then you may still have to write messy
     django response handling code with polling, long polling or
     websockets. The resulting code is super bloated and messy compared
     to pure async server code. It is better to completely leave out
     django from this game and solve the problem with communication
     between the client and your async helper directly. (Update: It is
     possible to combine gevent+django to make django async-ish but I
     didn't yet have the opportunity to try it on large scale to find
     out how solid is that solution and it isn't the way most people
     use django.)
2. Server-side validation of the text behind the URL, hiding th URL from
   the client, etc... You may or may not need these and they can
   influence which solution you choose.

## At Which layer should you put the meat of your solution?

Possible choices:

1. Client layer
2. View layer
3. Form layer
4. Model layer

### 1. Client layer

If it isn't a problem that your client knows about the external service
and directly communicates with it then this is probably the simplest solution. Implementing async access to the external service is
straightforward in javascript. The backend just provides a url that can be read and updated by the client and the rest of the job can be done in javascript.

### 2. View layer

I think putting the management of this whole thing to the view
layer isn't a good idea. People tend to stuff everything to the view
for some reason (perhaps because it seems to be the "easiest point of
attack" in case of adding new code). In my opinion the view shouldn't
do much more than parsing the input from the request for the business
logic (and validating it with/without forms) and then formatting the
response for the client. Ideally the view contains only glue code that makes use of other facilities (like forms, your own business logic in another module, etc...).

### 3. Form layer

When you implement validation of client requests the form layer is
usually the first place to consider. The job of the form is to transform and validate data between the client and the business logic. A quite often used special case of business logic simply validates the incoming data and saves it to the DB. To simplify this special case `ModelForm` comes to the rescue and generates a form skeleton from a model that can be customized with some minimal logic that validates the data. However in other cases the client data and the model layout may be different and there can be complex business logic between the form layer and the model layer, in that case `ModelForm` isn't useful.

#### Validation in form layer VS view layer

It is better to put validation to forms than into the view because
forms are more reusable. Well, you can provide your own reusable
validator utility functions/base-classes but still, forms have been
provided exactly for this purpose as a specialized standard solution.
With forms people implement validation in a more or less standard
and controlled way you would expect while in case of putting custom
logic into the views and validator utility functions/base classes,
people generate a lot of messy code for you to read and these code
snippets will always look different.
Forms can often be written in a declarative way that lowers the
chances of introducing bugs and makes reading code easier because
you know what to expect.

#### Validation in form layer VS model layer

Besides the specialized and declarative nature of forms there is
another reason why is it a better layer for validation than the model
layer: forms is a higher level layer and validation is also often
a high level operation. It may seem a good idea to put fancy
validation and tricky logic into your db models' `save` and `pre_save`
signal until you have to access and/or fix the raw DB directly
for some reason. It can also cause a lot of undesired conflicts
between your features using models. For practical reasons it is good
to have a low level layer that can be accessed without triggering
fancy higher level logic.

#### Your solution as a form field

In case of the from layer you often put your code into a from class to provide a solution that can be reused between several views. However in some special cases it is possible and better to go a bit lower level and provide your solution as a form field when reusability matters. This way your solution will be reusable between from classes that is better than reusability between views. Your problem is a special case that can be solved with a form field. Your form field should provide a textarea for the client and it should convert the incoming client text using pastebin into a url (and vice versa). This way the form field could be used to cooperate with a URL model field. You could even create a specialized `URLField` that uses your formfield as its default form field when someone generates form from a model with `ModelForm`.

### 4. Model layer

Your solution can also be implemented as a custom model field that provides its own less-meaty form field. This is somewhat more complicated than implementing the form field solution and you have to touch lower level layers of django that usually isn't recommended. Your code will be more fragile and sensitive to django version updates. Writing a
custom model field can be a real pain in the ass. I've done it once and I didn't like the journey. (When I had to deal with making the field compatible with south migrations... :-P)
There is a "Writing custom model fields" page in the django
documentation and even that doc states that writing them isn't
straightforward and recommends reading the source code of existing
fields for inspiration.

In case of the model field solution I think the pastebin model field
would be very similar to the standard `FileField`. Both of these fields
basically store the value in an external storage and they store only
an id to the database. Instead of writing our completely separate model field we could subclass and specialize `FileField`. We could replace its default storage with a patebin storage and the associated default form field and widget should also be customized.

---

## Update

We have discussed 3 possible solutions:

1. Client layer implementation: The backend provides a `URLField` and the client uses the url to directly communicate with the external service.
2. Form layer implementation: Using a custom form field that provides a `Textarea` widget and converts back-and-forth between the `URLField` of the model and the text area of the frontend by accessing the external service.
3. Model layer implementation: Providing a `FileField`-like model field or customizing `FileField` itself.

The first one is quite straightforward to implement for someone with some javascript knowledge. From the second and third solutions I think the third one is more complex, let's see a possible implementation of it. Key points:

- I've tried to subclass `FileField` in a minimally invasive way to make the solution less fragile. The subclassing changes the default storage and the default form field associated with `FileField` (and adds an optional caching optimization without which the solution would still work).
- The implementation contains a pastebin-specialized storage for our specialized `FileField`.
- The custom form field converts between the text of a textarea and the contents of a pastebin file of our model field.
- I've tried this code with success using django 1.8 and python 3.5.1 and I don't plan supporting any versions, this code is here just to provide a guideline. Use it at your own risk. If it cuts down your limbs, it is your problem. :-D

### Files

*pastebin/storage.py:*

```
import io
import requests
from django.core.files import File
from django.core.files.storage import Storage
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.deconstruct import deconstructible


@deconstructible
class PastebinStorage(Storage):
    def __init__(self, options=None):
        """ The options parameter should be a dict of pastebin parameters for
        the 'create new paste' operation: see http://pastebin.com/api#2
        The most important required option is api_dev_key. Optionally you can
        set api_user_key you want to create non-guest pastes. """
        self.__options = getattr(settings, 'PASTEBIN_STORAGE_OPTIONS', {})
        if options is not None:
            self.__options.update(options)

    @property
    def options(self):
        if 'api_dev_key' not in self.__options:
            raise ValueError('The "api_dev_key" option is missing')
        return self.__options

    def _save(self, name, content):
        # TODO: allow overriding the options on a per-file basis. Maybe we
        # should encode options into the name since we don't use it and
        # we return a completely new name/id at the end of this method.
        data = self.options.copy()
        data.update(
            api_option='paste',
            api_paste_code=content.read(),
        )
        response = requests.post('http://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php', data=data)
        response.raise_for_status()
        # A successful response contains something like: http://pastebin.com/<PASTE_KEY>
        return response.text[response.text.rfind('/')+1:]

    def _open(self, name, mode='rb'):
        if mode != 'rb':
            raise ValueError('Currently the only supported mode is "rb"')

        if 'api_user_key' in self.options:
            content = self._get_user_paste(name)
        else:
            content = self._get_public_paste(name)

        mem_stream = io.StringIO(content)
        mem_stream.name = name
        mem_stream.mode = mode
        return File(mem_stream)

    def _get_user_paste(self, name):
        response = requests.post('http://pastebin.com/api/api_raw.php', data=dict(
            api_dev_key=self.options['api_dev_key'],
            api_user_key=self.options['api_user_key'],
            api_option='show_paste',
            api_paste_key=name,
        ))
        # FIXME: Unfortunately the API seems to return status_code 200
        # also in case of errors with messages like "Bad API request,
        # invalid permission to view this paste or invalid api_paste_key"
        # in the body.
        response.raise_for_status()
        return response.text

    def _get_public_paste(self, name):
        response = requests.get('http://pastebin.com/raw/' + name)
        response.raise_for_status()
        return response.text

    def get_valid_name(self, name):
        return name

    def get_available_name(self, name, max_length=None):
        return name
```

*pastebin/model_field.py:*

```
from django.db.models import FileField
from django.db.models.fields.files import FieldFile

from .storage import PastebinStorage
from .form_field import PastebinFormField


default_storage = PastebinStorage()


# This custom FieldFile implementation is an optional optimization.
class PastebinContentCachingFieldFile(FieldFile):
    def cached_get_pastebin_content(self):
        cached = getattr(self, '_cached_pastebin_content', None)
        if cached and cached[0] == self.name:
            return cached[1]
        with self.storage.open(self.name) as f:
            content = f.read()
        setattr(self, '_cached_pastebin_content', (self.name, content))
        return content


class PastebinModelField(FileField):
    attr_class = PastebinContentCachingFieldFile

    def __init__(self, verbose_name=None, name=None, storage=None, **kwargs):
        storage = storage or default_storage
        super(PastebinModelField, self).__init__(verbose_name, name, storage=storage, **kwargs)

    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        defaults = {'form_class': PastebinFormField}
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super(PastebinModelField, self).formfield(**defaults)
```

*pastebin/form_field.py:*

```
import io

from django.core.files import File
from django.forms import Textarea, CharField


class PastebinFormField(CharField):
    widget = Textarea

    def prepare_value(self, value):
        if value is None or isinstance(value, str):
            return value
        # value is expected to be a PastebinContentCachingFieldFile instance
        return value.cached_get_pastebin_content()

    def to_python(self, data):
        data = super(PastebinFormField, self).to_python(data)
        if data is not None:
            mem_stream = io.StringIO(data)
            mem_stream.name = 'unused'
            mem_stream.mode = 'rb'
            data = File(mem_stream)
        return data
```

### Usage

The storage uses the `requests` library: `pip install requests`.

Optionally provide some default pastebin storage settings in the central django settings file. A minimal example can be something like:

```
PASTEBIN_STORAGE_OPTIONS = {
    'api_dev_key' : '<your_api_dev_key>',
}
```

If you provide the pastebin config in the django settings file then using the pastebin `FileField` in your models is as simple as:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    file = PastebinModelField()
```

If you don't specify anything in django settings or if you want to override the django settings you can do that per-field:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    file = PastebinModelField(storage=PastebinStorage(options=dict(
        api_dev_key='<your_dev_key>',
        api_user_key='<your_user_key>',
        ...
    )))
```

`ModelForm` automatically generates a textarea with the contents of the pastebin file for `PastebinModelField`. Saving with `ModelForm` creates a new pastebin file for `PastebinModelField`.

Comment: If it were possible to give a gold star alongside the bounty, I would.

Answer (score 3):

I think form can do all the magic required here:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    # use the widget to make a text area
    field5_text = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        # you already have four fields from the model and field5 from the form
        # add in this list so we get it in `cleaned_data`
        fields = ('field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4', 'field5_text')

    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # at this point you have to check whether you are editing or creating
        # a new one

        # if edit
        if self.instance.pk:
            text= get_text_from_url(self.instance.url_field_name)
            # get the text from response and set it as initial value for 
            # field5_text, for demonstration I am using text but you can get 
            # the actual value and set it here
            self.fields['field5_text'].initial = response.text

    def save(self, commit=True):

        # get the text value from cleaned_data and remove it because 
        # we don't want it to be saved with the form 
        text = self.cleaned_data.pop('field5_text')

        # get the instance by saving the form
        instance = super(MyForm, self).save(commit)

        # get the url by processing this text however you want it
        url = process_text_using_service(text)

        # set the url on the instance
        instance.url_field_name= url
        instance.save()

        return instance
```

**Key Points**

In `__init__` method there is a call to get the text from url and set it to the text field. You can write your own implementation for  `get_text_from_url` function:

```
if self.instance.pk:
    text= get_text_from_url(self.instance.url_field_name)
    self.fields['field5_text'].initial = text
```

And, further in `save` method, you can write your implementation to get the url  by processing the `text` received in the form `process_text_using_service` and then set it to the instance:

```
text = self.cleaned_data.pop('field5_text')
url = process_text_using_service(text)
```

Please do note that it is just an idea and not full working code so I am not really doing any error handling which I am sure you could if required.

Answer (score 2):

This is a **VERY** minimal example, it uses an `Item` model, which has a name and a url field.  On form submission, make a request to the external service, if the request is successful then store the url I want and save it in the model.

The form itself has a `name` and a `description`(the text field in html).

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django import forms
from items.models import Item
import requests


class ItemForm(forms.Form):

    def is_valid(self):
        # validate your textfield input then
        # make request to external service
        if super(ItemForm, self).is_valid():
            response = requests.get(some url)
            if response.status_code == 200:
                #if your request was successful...
                self.returned_url = #get url returned here
            else:
                # if your request was not successful, the form is invalid
                return False
            return True
        else:
            return False

    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = forms.CharField()

    #view to handle request
    def item_form_submit(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ItemForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                # if your form is valid, meaning you made a 
                # successful request to the external 
                # service and got your url you wanted
                # then create your object
                Item.objects.create(name=form.cleaned_data['name'],
                                    url=form.returned_url)
```

The template:

```
<form  action="/item_form_submit" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input name="name" type="text"/>
  <textarea name="description"></textarea>
  <button type="submit">
    Submit
  </button>
</form>
```

The model:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    url = models.URLField()
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript level

I would try to do it purely on client level, in JavaScript code. In this case Django backend would not be aware of Pastebin at all. Django outputs simple one line text field in form and link when model is displayed. JavaScript code process the rest.

Also, if necessary, call to Pastebin can be proxied via backend.

I find this approach much simpler than other ones. We must strive for simplicity first. Who would disagree?

I did exactly the same with images: images are uploaded using AJAX to simple Django view, shown to user and then only image URLs were posted when form is submitted. With images, it's only way to show what was uploaded and provide user-friendly validation experience. Think what would happen if user typed something invalid.

Advantages:

- faster response;
- no problems with external services (e.g. banning your machine by IP address, limiting connections);
- cleaner server code.

Disadvantages:

- Pastebin URL is revealed;
- there is some JavaSctipt code to write.

Honestly, I don't think that these disadvantages can make a problem.

## View level

View should be kept simple. Although I prefer to have interaction with external service in view. (Or, if it's too bulky, it can be extracted to function.) Create form with text field, process it directly in view and create model manually.

## Model level

You can try to create separate Pastebin record model. It makes sense for me that it makes external call to Pastebin when saving.

## Other approaches

Keeping call to external service in models or forms is possible but ask yourself, if you were new developer on project with this problem solved, where would you expect to find external call? Forms are made to output HTML form, receive input and validate data. Models are made to abstract from databases; I wouldn't start interaction with Pastebin until model is not made especially for that.